# c function to merge bytes

Tags: c, byte

I have to write function in c to merge bytes from two unsigned int parameters,
taking the most significant byte of the second param and the rest of the first param.

For example if given `x = 0x89ABCDEF` and `y = 0x76543210` so the function should return `0x76ABCDEF`

now I know that `char *c = (char*) &y` will give me the MSB of y but then I don't know how to chain it to the rest of x without his MSB.

To be honest I completely forgot to do such simple thing in C as in last year all of my courses used Java, and I can't find it online, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (y & 0xff000000) | (x & 0x00ffffff) ... but how does it work? - edited

Comment: Are you making the assumption that `unsigned` is exactly 32 bits wide?  What should the code do if it is 64 bits instead?  You might want to use `uint32_t` if you mean 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for bit masking:

```
unsigned merge(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    return (y & 0xFF000000) | (x & 0xFFFFFF);
}
```

Assuming 32-bit values, this used a bitwise AND to strip all but the top byte from `y` and only the top byte from `x`, then uses a bitwise OR to merge them togther.

Comment: @GradyPlayer What do you call `y >> 24`?

Comment: @GradyPlayer Doh!  Fixed.

Comment: Does C11 still allow omitting `int`?

Comment: @user4464936 Yes, it makes no assumption about endianness.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support a known-length integer field using bitwise operators is the right choice, like others suggested. But I would answer your specific question using a char pointer this way:

```
unsigned int result;

char * rPtr = (char*) &result;
char * xPtr = (char*) &x;

*xPtr++;
*rPtr++ = *((char*)&y);
for(i = 1; i < sizeof(result); i++) {
    *rPtr++ = *xPtr++;
}
```

Comment: OP has implied that his/her machine is big endian. `now I know that char *c = (char*) &y will give me the MSB of y `

Comment: @user3528438 thanks, actually I did not get what MSB meant